# Impresión de listas en python?

Tags: python, print

Estoy realizando unos ejercicios de las Listas de python, y me encontre con el siguiente problema: Al usar el operador aritmetico * para repetir lista y tratar de imprimirla con la función `print`, no logro separar las listas.
¿Como puedo lograr que la lista creada se imprima las veces que le indico, pero cada una en líneas diferente?

Ejemplo:

```py
lista=["jose",5,"Maria"]*5 #lista que mando a repetir 5 veces
print(lista[:]) #print para ver los elementos de la lista
```

Esto muestra todo junto y no se como separar las listas, para verlas en líneas distintas.

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Para hacer la pregunta mas clara y mas legible, por favor incluyas los codigos, la salida actual, y la salida esperada. Gracias.

Comment: Puede probar `print(*lista,sep='\n')`. El argumento `sep` es para especificar cual caracter quiere imprimir entre los elementos. Y el `\n` es newline (nueva linea).

Comment: te recomiendo `pprint` solo debes instalarlo con `pip install pprint` luego solo debes importar con `from pprint import pprint` y para usarlo solo haces `pprint(lista)` te formate el texto de forma legible y agradable a la vista!

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que ese operador como bien dijiste es para repetir lista, o mejor dicho para repetir el valor que contine ese lista n veces en otra nueva lista. Al final lo que tendras es 1 nueva lista (literal otra lista nueva en una direccion de memoria diferente) con los elementos de tu lista anterior repetido n veces.

Ejemplo:

```py
listA = [1,2,3]
listB = listA*3 #Este sera igual a [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

ya sabiendo esto no podras aplicar una regla de separacion entre listas ya que solo tienes 1 lista, para esto tendrias que escribir un poco mas de codigo.

Ejemplo:

```py
lista=["jose",5,"Maria"]
tamanoDeLista = len(lista)

repetir = 5
lista = lista*repetir

for i in range(0,repetir):
  indexFrom = i*tamanoDeLista
  indexTo = (i+1)*tamanoDeLista
  subLista = lista[indexFrom:indexTo]
  print(subLista)
```

Esta no es exactamente tu respuesta pero te da una idea de como seria en este caso.

Comment: Hola hiral2, exactamente es lo que sucede, es una sola lista que repite sus elementos, en este caso 5 veces. Lo que quise hacer es separar los elementos y mostrarlos como los creé en la lista original. evaluaré el código que me indicas, Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Solo considerando que quieres imprimir los elementos, ya que al multiplicar esa lista se formarán más elementos, no más listas:

```py
lista=["jose",5,"Maria"]*5 #lista que mando a repetir 5 veces
for x in lista:
    print(x) #print para ver los elementos de la lista
```

Ahora, si quieres imprimir la lista como tal 5 veces:

```py
lista=[("jose",5,"Maria")]*5 #lista de tupla que mando a repetir 5 veces
for x in lista:
    print (list(x)) #convierto las tuplas en listas e imprimo las listas
```

Y otra manera sería:

```py
lista=["jose",5,"Maria"] #lista
cont=0 
while cont<5:
    print (lista)
    cont+=1 #aumento el contador en 1 para que cuando llegue a 5 se hayan completado los 5 print
```

Comment: Hola, Claudia, si se repiten los elementos dentro de una misma lista, y mi idea era separarlos como la lista original. intentare con tus sentencias a ver que tal me va. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda